# Excel time calculations throwing errors when 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns where I'm calculating the difference between 2 times.  I only want to see the difference if it is not zero.  This is the formula I'm using without any issues:

=IF(TEXT(RC[-1]-R[-2]C[-1],"h:mm:ss")="0:00:00","",TEXT(RC[-1]-R[-2]C[-1],"h:mm:ss"))

I have 3 columns (3,6,9) where this forumla is used.  So far, so good.

I'd like to get an average of the 3 columns but am having issues with the getting the formula to work.

The problem is that on a specific row, only 1 or 2 columns may have values.  If one column is blank, I get a #VALUE! message when trying to sum the columns with this formula:

=RC[-8]+RC[-5]+RC[-2]

What I'm looking for is a formula that will give me an avg if there is 1 or 2 or 3 values, ignoring the ones that are blank.

Thanks for your help......

Comment: Use SUM to sum.... it will ignore the text (blank strings). If you want an average, use AVERAGE.

Comment: @bigben.....thanks......I'll give that a try....